# Listing exemplary questions on the "Help Center > Asking" page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions

Following the encouraging comments of several people who answered [a question I posted on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24724246/3372061), I looked more thoroughly at [the guidelines of question asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically searching for examples of questions whose structure, style and\or presentation is considered desirable on Stack Exchange.

Such questions are not necessarily especially up-voted or popular (since questions are, IMHO, mostly up-voted for describing a common or an interesting problem that many people encounter, rather than owing to the questions' structure), and their "true value" lies in their "didactic" qualities (i.e. being a well posed question).

Due to either a deficit of searching skills on my part or to the nonexistence of such a section, I was unable to find a list of inspiring questions.

For this reason, **I propose** making some mechanism by which questions are tagged as being good in the "meta" sense and these questions should be presented to users as templates to follow.

Ideas for such a mechanism may include:

- Allowing certain people (such as well-known contributors to meta or users with very high reputation) to flag\vote\suggest a question as being worthy, thereby presenting it to other reviewers for final approval.
- Separating the question\answer score into two different scores - a "content score" and a "meta score".
- Creating a separate "how to" portal and cloning especially good and bad examples in it. The posts in this sections would be ranked according to their meta-quality (thus allowing users to easily sort questions and view the entire spectrum of questions\answers).

P.S. This also goes for exemplary answers.

Comment: This, itself is a well worded question

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: [Show examples of good and bad questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179268)

Comment: If some mechanism is implemented, adding to it should be done only by a well chosen pool of people; otherwise it will just be "put most upvoted answers into that list" because when everyone can vote, they will not understand what this is for

Comment: @PlasmaHH - This is exactly what I had in mind. I forgot to mention it for some reason.. I'll update the question to reflect it.

Comment: You can see the highly voted (100+,200+) answers as exemplary answers, not the same for questions though.

Answer (score 2):

I find the exemplary answers proposal more useful than the exemplary questions one. Wouldn't a better guideline, if you didn't find the current one good enough, and maybe two examples be more useful?

Comment: I don't know about that: there are far more bad questions than there are bad answers.

Comment: And bad questions lead to bad answers (usually, there are some exceptions). Guesses, debugging enquiries, incorrect answers when the details eventually get pulled from the OP or the Question gets edited to describe the problem in a different way that invalidates any previous answers.

Comment: Agreed. My point is that most people won't necessarily improve the quality of their questions by seeing good ones somewhere else, if this is the point the OP was making. Other problems and issues require a different formulation and the structure of another good question is not always easily copied. By contrast, guidelines could possibly apply to a broader range of questions. OTOH, a page listing good questions could be an incentive to formulate better questions!

Comment: I disagree. From my point of view, when you've already landed on a certain question you think is interesting, there are usually a couple of answers at most, and it is easy to quickly tell which ones are good or bad based on the votes. On the other hand, when you're browsing a certain language tag trying to give some answers, you get thousands of questions plagued with bad, unclear, off-topic ones! You end up wasting your time looking for that decent comprehensible Q you can potentially answer..